# Visio road map editor issue

Tags: microsoft-visio

I am trying to create a basic directional road map in Visio and I would like the roads to be thin outlines (Bottom half of picture), instead of the black solid filled line (See top half of picture). I have tried editing/formatting the road feature and I am lost. How do I do this?  Googled but no dice.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using the standard road shapes in the Road Shapes stencil.

Right-click the shape on the drawing page and you can select **Thin**, **Standard** or **Thick** road. If these 3 options don't suit then you can use the standard line width menu to select any thickness you like.